# How to insert image in a React Ionic Project running on top of Capacitor?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor, ionic-react

I'm working on a `React Ionic Project`, running on `Android` and `iOS` and I'm using the latest versions of React, Ionic and Capacitor packages.

```
Ionic CLI       : 6.13.1 
Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 5.6.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 3.0.0
   @capacitor/core : 3.0.0
```

I would like to add an image in the following page:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  IonHeader,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
  IonIcon,
  IonMenuToggle,
  IonButton,
  IonButtons,
  IonImg,
} from "@ionic/react";
import { menuOutline } from "ionicons/icons";

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <IonHeader>
      <IonToolbar className="menu-header">
        <IonButtons slot="start">
          <IonMenuToggle>
            <IonButton>
              <IonIcon slot="icon-only" icon={menuOutline}></IonIcon>
            </IonButton>
          </IonMenuToggle>
        </IonButtons>
        <IonTitle>
          {/**insert the image here />*/}
         <img src="img1.png" alt="">
        </IonTitle>
      </IonToolbar>
    </IonHeader>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

I'm new to Ionic and I don't know in which folder to put the image, in order to be shown correctly **after** **building** the app and testing it on Android/iOS emulator. If someone would explain to me the process of inserting an image in the app, I would be really thankful.
Thank you!

Assets folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Add all your images in assets folder and use it like: `<img src="assets/imgs/yourImage.png" alt="">`

Comment: Please check my assets folder. There's no imgs folder inside it. Should I create it? What should I do?

Comment: you can directly put all image inside assets folder but for better understanding create imgs folder and put all images inside it.

Comment: oki, thank you :) Only one more question: My imgs folder will be included automatically in build folder after my command: `ionic build` ? Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: yes, it will be included. You don't have to do anything.